# Java - Server listens on many ports

Tags: java, server, nio, ports

I have some simple code in my server that waits for a client to connect on port 4444

```
try {
  serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    //blah
}

while (true) {
  try {
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    //do something
} catch (IOException ex) {
    //blah
}
```

I now what to expand to have my server listen on 10 different ports. At first I was looking at something like: `for (int i = 4444; i < 4454; i++)` but that didn't work properly.

Now I'm looking into Java NIO ServerSocketChannel. I found this code online (thanks @Dunes!)

```
Selector selector = Selector.open();

int[] ports = {4000,4001,6000};

for (int port : ports) {
   ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
   server.configureBlocking(false);

   server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
   // we are only interested when accept evens occur on this socket
   server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT); 
}

while (selector.isOpen()) {
   selector.select();
   Set readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
   Iterator iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
      if (key.isAcceptable()) {
         SocketChannel client = server.accept(); //SERVER CANNOT BE RESOLVED!!!!
         Socket socket = client.socket();
         // create new thread to deal with connection (closing both socket and client when done)
      }
   }
}
```

But I can't execute it. On the `while (iterator.hasNext())` block, `server` in `server.accept` says that "server cannot be resolved". Why is that? Is `NIO ServerSocketChannel` the right thing I'm suppose to be doing to have my server listen on many ports? If not, what's the best method for my server to accept many ports?

Comment: Are you sure you understand how the ServerSocket is intended to work? You understand that when a Socket connection is made through a ServerSocket, that connection is moved to another port so that the ServerSocket can keep listening. If you understand this, then may I ask: Why do you want to run your ServerSocket on multiple ports?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'm still pretty new to coding so I probably don't really understand everything fully. Basically, I have an android chat app. So if ClientA wants to talk to ClientB, they will through localport 4444. And then if ClientC wants to talk to ClientD, they will through localport 5555.

Comment: @EJP What would you suggest I do instead, since I'm using TCP sockets? I'm confused in that if ClientA wants to talk to ClientB, they can both connect through localport444. And if ClientC wants to talk directly to ClientD, then they can do that on localport5555. At least that makes the most sense to me... thanks!

Comment: Use a single port. Presumably your protocol tells the server which target each new client wants to connect to. That's all you need.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Are you sure you know what you're talking about? It is **not** 'moved to another port', but there can certainly be large numbers of inbound connections to a listening port.

Comment: @EJP Okay, thanks! I'm a little confused though on how my "protocol tells the server which target each new client wants to connect to". So it would be something like... Server listens on port 4444. ClientA connects to 4444. ClientB connects to 4444. ClientC connects to 4444. ClientD connects to 4444. How do I connect client A and B?

Comment: @EJP If I am wrong about redirecting incoming connections to other ports, then how does this mechanism work? I know from experience that when a ServerSocket accepts more than 1 connection, each Socket generated in Accept has unique Input/OutputStreams, that aren't shared with other connections. So can you explain to me/us the mechanism for that routing?

Comment: @Pam The client has to tell you who he is and who he wants to connect to. Then you just copy data between those pairs of sockets.

Comment: @ControlAltDel InputStreams and OutputStreams are not ports. The accepted sockets are distinct: that is sufficient. Have a look at a `netstat` output in a server. You will see large numbers of lines in ESTABLISHED state, all with the same local port number. This is hardly the place for a tutorial on elementary TCP/IP.

Comment: I see no reason for these unexplained downvotes, and there is nothing whatsoever unclear about the question.

Comment: @Pam You should consider upvoting or accept any answer(s) you find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you think you need this, but your compilation error should be resolved as follows:

```
ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel)key.channel();
SocketChannel client = server.accept();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious error in your code...

```
SocketChannel client = server.accept(); //SERVER CANNOT BE RESOLVED!!!!
```

As @EJP mentioned, it would need to be replaced with...

```
ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel)key.channel();
SocketChannel client = server.accept();
```

However, while you *can* use ports to distinguish clients, if you think about it for a second, it doesn't scale.  You're immediately limiting the number of clients to the number of available ports.  What's worse though, you're preventing other applications from using those ports (possibly all available ports).  As @EJP also mentioned, you need to define an appropriate protocol over the sockets.

You may want to take a look at the java sockets [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).  It doesn't go into NIO, but it will give a basic idea of how these things are normally done.